# Styling text onscreen using the <p> tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am developing a game using JavaScript and I want to have the scenes of a classic 1990's game where the text appears in split-second intervals then disappears once the user clicks next. Is there a way to do this just using JavaScript?

I'm using PhpStorm for the moment. I have yet to start as I'm designing the blueprints with my friend. I am also a bit confused about where to start because I have searched for methods but no luck.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible - but for specific answers, you question is rather too vague to begin with.

Comment: I apologize, I will phrase it better and present code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Since You Are Making A Game You Will Be Having A Canvas Too

So Use This Code If have Any Questions Ask Me

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myTitle;

//Function To Start the Game
function startGame() {
    myTitle = new component("20px", "Consolas", "black", 150, 135, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

// myGameArea Is The Canvas in Which The Whole Drawing Process Will be Drawn & The Title Is Drawn In This Too
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
// setInterval Function Draws the Canvas 50 times in a Second You Can Change The Value Of  50 IF You Want
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 50);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
}

// Component Function Makes a New Component Like We Have A Title By Component Function
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height; 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
// This Checks if Component Type is Text And Every Frame is Divided By 70 Then Nothing Will Happen Else Your Title Will Appear You Glitch is Because Of This Function You Can The Value As You Want

        if (this.type == "text" && everyinterval(70) ) {

        } else {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        }
    }

}
// This Function Updates GameArea (The Canvas) I Added The Frame No So You Can See The Glitch At Every Frame Number

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    myGameArea.clear();
  myTitle.text = "Title Glitching at " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myTitle.update();

}

// The Function To Make The Glitch Which Divide's The FrameNo By "n" Number
function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thank you for the code but do you know how to make the letters pop up one by one in that box just using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by pop up an Example will be helpful

Comment: I want the text to appear like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycsnBIX8wTU

Comment: Watch at 23 seconds.

Comment: check this:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp